# Sqlite. Как составить запрос по составному primary ключу

Tags: android, sqlite

Мне требуется из таблицы получить содержимое столбца  `number`.   У меня `PRIMARY KEY(surname,name)` (таблица только для примера).  Делаю запрос чтобы он вернул мне значение столбца `number` и если по такому составному ключу ничего нет, то делаю запрос в интернет.  
 Вот как я думаю `DataBase.rawQuery("SELECT number FROM TableName WHERE PRIMARY KEY = Surname, Name);` И что  я получу по такому запросу? Курсор? И потом надо его еще проверить на null?  А что будет, если по данному ключу нет никакой записи? он вернет null или что то другое?

**UPD** 
 использовал вместо rawQuery просто query. Есть в SQL такое что можно писать AND?  Такой запрос мне выдаст запись из поля number по данному имени и фамилии

```
Cursor c = DataBase.query("MyTable",
                new String[]{"number"},
                "name = ? AND surname = ? ",
               new String[] {"Иван","Иванов"),
               null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int idColNumber = c.getColumnIndex("number");
            String number = c.getString(idColNumber);
            c.close();
            System.out.println("Выборка " + number);
         }
```

мм..вроде дошло что то: получается, что вместо вопроса подставляется первый аргумент из массива и  для name и для surname. А как сделать так, чтобы первый аргумент был для name, a второй для surname?

Comment: *что я получу по такому запросу?* Наиболее вероятно - Syntax Error.

Comment: Так вопрос как раз в том, что мне нужна помощь с составлением запроса именно по составному ключу.

Comment: Забудь о существовании ключа. Запросы работают только с полями записей. Индексы, в т.ч. первичный, могут лишь способствовать ускорению обработки, а также использоваться для контроля целостности.

Comment: ну пусть будет в запросе написано, не primary key , а имена тех двух полей, которые входят в состав первичного ключа

Comment: Типо: WHERE name = Name AND surname = Surmane

Comment: Угу... Вот только поскольку тип данных полей `name` и `surname` почти наверняка текстовый, то при сравнении со строковыми литералами последние следует обрамлять кавычками. И, возможно, потребуются дополнительные телодвижения - для управления регистрочувствительностью сравнения и преобразования кодировок.

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли, что мне не понятно. Я добавил в вопрос. Тут не с регистром беда, а с тем как правильно запрос сделать. я понимаю так, что если будет OR то будет выборка где либо имя совпадает с тем что в запросе, либо фамилия. А если ставлю AND то выборка, где совпадает и имя и фамилия. Так ли работает? Просто я разобрался как в sqlite всё это делается и остался вопрос синтаксиса.

Comment: Я знаю что в запросе по данному имени и фамилии у меня есть результат. Но я его не получаю, если  использую AND

Comment: ММ, разобрался наконец то. Основная причина была несколько в другом, а приложенный к вопросу код исправно работает.  Всё задумано именно так как я думал в начале: первый аргумент для name, а второй для surname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш запрос должен обрабатываться корректно, то есть каждому новому знаку вопроса подставляется следующий аргумент из массива.

Стоит обратить внимание, что использовать в качестве первичного ключа сами данные несколько неразумно, так как они не уникальны. Вполне может быть два и более Иванов Ивановых и вы никак не сможете отличить одного от другого.
Обычно в качестве первичного ключа используется отдельный столбец ID, более того, в Android этот столбец должен **присутствовать обязательно**,  **именоваться** не иначе, **как *_id*** и столбец этот должен быть **включен в выборку курсора**, иначе часть стандартных классов Android по работе с SQLite не будет работать корректно.

Для того, чтобы получить значение одного столбца по совпадению в других столбцах, не обязательно (вовсе не требуется) назначать их первичным ключом, достаточно сделать выборку по нужному столбцу и включить интересующие столбцы в эту выборку, затем получить значение из нужного столбца в полученной выборке (именно это и делает ваш код в вопросе, никакой первичный ключ вы при этом не используете)

Узнать больше по работе с реляционными базами данных можно из книги Бейли Л. - Изучаем SQL (Бестселлеры O'Reilly) - 2012. Если вы ничего не знали о СУБД и собираетесь как то использовать, то прочитать ее надо обязательно перед тем, как начать. Дисциплина это такая, что интуицией и методом тыка тут не прорвешься.

Comment: ну тут я просто привел пример для простоты. А у меня первый столбец дата, второй валюта и если их рассматривать вместе они уникальны и перед созданием таблицы объявлены первичным ключом.  Но как я понял запрос по первичному ключу не делается, но запрос по этим двум столбцам дает мне всегда нужную строку.

Comment: Первичным ключом я их назначил потому, что все время база пополняется и дублироваться записи не должны.

Comment: А вот насчет _id . Почему обязательно. Допустим в моей базе одна строка на один день. Т.е. столбец дата уже уникален, зачем мне еще _id.  Ну для удобства я могу его назвать _idDate, чтобы было понятно, что это уникальный столбец.

Comment: столбец  _id нужен для коректной работы классов, связанны с sqlite в андроид, как итерирование курсора, а не для вашего удобства

Comment: т.е. хоть у  меня есть всегда уникальный столбец, мне надо все равно завести еще и _id ? Итерирование будет работать корректно, если я свой уникальный столбец назову _id, но при этом значения в нём не последовательно растущие числа, а что то типо 123, 456, 789.?

Comment: ID это уникальный идентификатор, единственное требование к нему - уникальность (не может быть одинаковых значений в таблице), никакого последовательно растущего числа от него не требуется. его назначение - однозначно и надежно идентифицировать запись. в андроид такой идентификатор должен называться только  *_id* (не ID, _ID, IDDATA, _DATA или как то еще) и содержать число типа INTEGER, иначе часть методов стандартных классов андроид по работе с sqlite не будет работать, так же этот столбец должен быть включен в выборку курсора

Comment: ну да моя дата уникальна, но она в unixTime и длина больше чем может хранить INTEGER. хотя нееет. INTEGER но по 8 байт. значит мне надо просто переименовать её правильно